Holomorphic radius vector
Given $P(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)):U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ an isothermal parametrization, it is a fact that the image of $P$ is a minimal surface if and only if $x,y,z$ are harmonic. We can then define three complex functions through the complex operator $$\varphi_1(u+iv)=\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}(u+iv):=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(u,v)-i\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}(u,v)\right)$$ Similarly with $y,z$. It holds that $P$ is isothermal if and only if $\varphi_1^2+\varphi_2^2+\varphi_3^2=0$ and $\varphi_i$ are holomorphic if and only if $x,y,z$ are harmonic. So in order to study minimal surfaces we turn the attention to triples of holomorphic functions $(\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3)$ named holomorphic radius vector.
Conversly, and here's the problem, given three holomorphic functions defined on a simply connected subset $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3:U\subseteq\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2+\phi_3^2=0$ we can define a surface given by the following parametrization
$$x^k(u,v)=2\cdot\Re\left(\int_{z_0}^{u+iv}\phi_k(w)dw\right)$$
Where $\Re$ defines the real part. I cannot understand why this triple $x^k$ defines a minimal surface. Specifically, I have to prove the identity $\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}=\phi_1$ for the parametrization to be isothermal, and then $\nabla^2x=0$ in order to define a minimal surface. But I cannot compute these two expressions in terms of $\phi_i$. Any help would be hugely appreciated.
